# Open a node in a block when selected in a View

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, nodes, open-atrium

I been searching with no luck so far for this functionality. I want to display a view, and then allow the user to select an item in the view. Then display either a popup of that nodes information or display that information in a block on the right.

Currently building a feature in Open Atrium and this functionality would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Colorbox module](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox) to open up the link in a "lightbox" popup. You'd need to override the default row theme for the view, to trigger the lightbox. Or you might be able to trigger the lightbox by rewriting the output of an individual field in the view.

Comment: hmmm... I could yet trying to do this without any dev. I just found http://drupal.org/project/popups and giving that a go.